# Working with umlaut in CKAN pages-extension

Tags: ckan

In the pages-extension of CKAN I filled the content with a text including an umlaut (ü).

After saving the page, it shows "[HTML_REMOVED]" at this position. Same happens, as expected, when I use an html entity (`&uuml;`) for the umlaut.

Is there a way to publish words with a umlaut?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution: In the pages-extension you have to modify the plugin.py:

```
allow_html = toolkit.asbool(config.get('ckanext.pages.allow_html', False))
```

-->

```
allow_html = toolkit.asbool(config.get('ckanext.pages.allow_html', True))
```

Compile the file and it will work as it is interpreting the umlaut in html now correctly.